# Tikz - better way of scaling and positioning reusable parts

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, scaling

I have some Tikz figures which I use in multiple other figures. Right now I put them in a scope and use xshift/yshift/scale to place them at the position I want them to be. I have one example. I need a figure in a LaTeX document which has a \linewidth of 336pt, thus I want to work on my picture with this width in mind. I start by creating a frame of the desired width and scale. Next I want some boxes in it with some content. One of the boxes contains a stickman which I use in other figures as well. My current solution looks like this:

Here is one example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt]

    % Stickman
    \begin{scope}[xshift=38pt, yshift=105pt, anchor=sout west, scale=0.45,local bounding box=person]
        \draw[thin, line cap=round] (0.05,1) -- (-0.05, 1.1); % hair1
        \draw[thin, line cap=round] (-0.05,1) -- (-0.2, 1.12); % hair1
        \draw[thick] (0,0) circle [radius=1]; % head

        \draw[thin] plot [smooth,tension=1.5] coordinates{(-0.7,0.45) (-0.5,0.52) (-0.4,0.52)}; % leyebrow
        \draw[fill=black] (-0.5,0.25) ellipse (0.1 and 0.15);
        \draw[thin] plot [smooth,tension=1.5] coordinates{(0.3,0.40) (0.1,0.50) (-0.1,0.50)}; % leyebrow
        \draw[fill=black] (0.1,0.20) ellipse (0.1 and 0.15);

        \draw[thick] plot [smooth,tension=1.5] coordinates{(-0.75,-0.4) (-0.2,-0.6) (0.3,-0.53)}; % mouth

        \draw[thick] (-0.15,-1) .. controls (-0.4,-2.5) .. (-0.5,-4); % torso

        \draw[thick] (-0.2,-1.3) -- (0.35, -2.55) -- (1.5, -2.2); % rarm
        \draw[thick,rotate around={110:(1.5, -2.2)}] (1.5, -2.4) ellipse (0.1 and 0.2);
        \draw[thick] (-0.2,-1.3) -- (-1.55, -2.55) -- (-1.75, -4.1); % rarm
        \draw[thick,rotate around={-5:(-1.75, -4.1)}] (-1.75, -4.3) ellipse (0.1 and 0.2);

        \draw[thick] (-0.5,-4) -- (0.7, -5.3) -- (1.4,-6.8); % rleg
        \draw[thick,rotate around={25:(1.4,-6.8)}] (1.65,-6.8) ellipse (0.25 and 0.1);
        \draw[thick] (-0.5,-4) -- (-0.95,-5.8) -- (-2.3,-7); % rleg
        \draw[thick,rotate around={-35:(-2.3,-7)}] (-2.05,-7) ellipse (0.25 and 0.1);
    \end{scope}

    \tikzstyle{box}=[draw, very thick, minimum height=120pt] % box style
    % Stickman Box
    \node[box, anchor=south west, minimum width=60pt] (FrameInput) at (5pt, 5pt) {};
    \node[above=of FrameInput] (xy) {Input};

    % Second box
    \node[box, minimum width=120pt, right=of FrameInput, xshift=15pt] (FrameNextStep) {};
    \node[above=of FrameNextStep] (xy) {NextStep};

    % Box Connections
    \path[->, very thick] (FrameInput) edge (FrameNextStep);

    % Picture Frame
    \draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (336pt, 150pt); % frame
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This results in the following image:
[image]

I just wonder if there are better ways to solve this. e.g. by specifying my stickman should have a max width / height which equals to the FrameInput box without manually tuning the scale parameter of the scope. The same applies for the x/y shift, is there a better / more elegant way for positioning it?

Comment: To create multiple copies of an image, one can use a pic or savebox.  The savebox would include an entire tikzpicture and is placed into a node using \usebox.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I ended up using a pic and, if required, its local bounding box for edges to/from the pic.

Answer (score 2):

1. calculate the width and height and lowerleft anchor of original stickman in a `pgfinterruptboundingbox` environment.
2. calculate the shift offset and scale value
3. draw the correct stickman with lowerleft corner at `(0, 0)`

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  stickman height/.store in=\stickman@height,
  stickman height=2cm,
  stickman x sep/.store in=\stickman@x@sep,
  stickman x sep=3pt,
  stickman y sep/.store in=\stickman@y@sep,
  stickman y sep=3pt,
}
\gdef\@stickman{
  \draw[thin, line cap=round] (0.05,1) -- (-0.05, 1.1); % hair1
  \draw[thin, line cap=round] (-0.05,1) -- (-0.2, 1.12); % hair1
  \draw[thick] (0,0) circle [radius=1]; % head

  \draw[thin] plot [smooth,tension=1.5] coordinates{(-0.7,0.45) (-0.5,0.52) (-0.4,0.52)}; % leyebrow
  \draw[fill=black] (-0.5,0.25) ellipse (0.1 and 0.15);
  \draw[thin] plot [smooth,tension=1.5] coordinates{(0.3,0.40) (0.1,0.50) (-0.1,0.50)}; % leyebrow
  \draw[fill=black] (0.1,0.20) ellipse (0.1 and 0.15);

  \draw[thick] plot [smooth,tension=1.5] coordinates{(-0.75,-0.4) (-0.2,-0.6) (0.3,-0.53)}; % mouth

  \draw[thick] (-0.15,-1) .. controls (-0.4,-2.5) .. (-0.5,-4); % torso

  \draw[thick] (-0.2,-1.3) -- (0.35, -2.55) -- (1.5, -2.2); % rarm
  \draw[thick,rotate around={110:(1.5, -2.2)}] (1.5, -2.4) ellipse (0.1 and 0.2);
  \draw[thick] (-0.2,-1.3) -- (-1.55, -2.55) -- (-1.75, -4.1); % rarm
  \draw[thick,rotate around={-5:(-1.75, -4.1)}] (-1.75, -4.3) ellipse (0.1 and 0.2);

  \draw[thick] (-0.5,-4) -- (0.7, -5.3) -- (1.4,-6.8); % rleg
  \draw[thick,rotate around={25:(1.4,-6.8)}] (1.65,-6.8) ellipse (0.25 and 0.1);
  \draw[thick] (-0.5,-4) -- (-0.95,-5.8) -- (-2.3,-7); % rleg
  \draw[thick,rotate around={-35:(-2.3,-7)}] (-2.05,-7) ellipse (0.25 and 0.1);
}
\newlength\pre@y@max
\newlength\pre@y@min
\newlength\pre@other
\tikzset{
  stickman/.pic={
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \begin{scope}[opacity=0, local bounding box=pre]
      \@stickman
    \end{scope}
    \path (pre.north);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\pre@other}{\pre@y@max}
    \path (pre.south);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\pre@other}{\pre@y@min}
    \pgfmathparse{(\stickman@height - 2*\stickman@y@sep)/(\pre@y@max - \pre@y@min)}
    \global\let\temp@scale\pgfmathresult
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \draw[line width=1pt] let \p1 = (pre.south west), \p2 = (pre.north west), \p3 = (pre.north east) in
      let \p{anchor} = ($(\stickman@x@sep,\stickman@y@sep)-\temp@scale*(pre.south west)$) in
      let \p{other} = ($2*(\stickman@x@sep,\stickman@y@sep)+\temp@scale*(\p3)-\temp@scale*(\p1)$) in
      coordinate (shift) at (\p{anchor})
      coordinate (clip) at (\p{other});
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=now]
      \draw[line width=1pt] (0, 0) rectangle (clip);
      \begin{scope}[scale=\temp@scale, shift=(shift)]
        \@stickman
      \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
    \coordinate (-north) at (now.north);
    \coordinate (-east) at (now.east);
    \coordinate (-west) at (now.west);
    \coordinate (-south east) at (now.south east);
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt]
  \pic [stickman height=3cm] (a) at (0, 0) {stickman};
  \pic [stickman height=3cm, xshift=1cm, stickman x sep=10pt] (b) at (a-south east) {stickman};
  \draw[->, very thick] (a-east) -- (b-west);
  \node[above] at (a-north) {Input};
  \node[above] at (b-north) {NextStep};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]